# I am trying to run postman collection with newman on Macbook but getting error

Tags: postman, postman-collection-runner, newman, macbookpro-touch-bar

I am trying to run a postman collection with newman on Macbook but getting the following error.

zsh: no matches found: https://api.getpostman.com/collections

I haven't shared complete URL due to reason.

Please let me know how can I fix this issue as I am new to using Macbook.

Answer (score 0):

You need to click on your profile image top right, then click settings, and then create an API key.

[image]

Once you have an API key add it to the Auth tab in your API call, with the key x-api-key and the value is your API key.

[image]

This link shows how to add the API key when running with Newman.

https://blog.postman.com/newman-run-and-test-your-collections-from-the-command-line/

Answer (score 0):

Use the below command

```
newman run "https://api.getpostman.com/collections"
```